# Query from Association of Associations Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations, query

I have a rather large dataset comprised of Association of Associations. For better or worse, I've converted this into a `Dataset`. Here is a simplified version of that dataset:

```
testdb = Dataset[<|
   "First" -> <|
     "LOCATION" -> GeoPosition[{40.1151, -88.2737}, "NAD27"], 
     "TYPE" -> "A", "DATA1" -> Range[10], 
     "DATA2" -> {0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.75, 0.15, 0.95, 0.4}|>,
   "Second" -> <|
     "LOCATION" -> GeoPosition[{40.1123, -89.110}, "NAD27"], 
     "TYPE" -> "B", "DATA1" -> Range[2, 11], 
     "DATA2" -> {0.3, 0.2, 0.24, 0.44, 0.2, 0.81, 0.76, 0.72, 0.88, 
       0.44}|>,
   "Third" -> <|
     "LOCATION" -> GeoPosition[{40.1123, -89.110}, "NAD27"], 
     "TYPE" -> "B", "DATA1" -> Range[4, 13], 
     "DATA2" -> {0.66, 0.65, 0.21, 0.92, 0.51, 0.44, 0.23, 0.77, 0.85,
        0.11}|>|>]
```

[image]

My end goal is to have a resulting dataset of `{"LOCATION","NEWDATA"}` where `NEWDATA` is the total of `"DATA2"` for corresponding values of `"DATA1"` between 5 and 8 (`5<=x<=8`).

So for the example above, the result would be:

[image]

The true dataset is of length 824 with nested datasets of 20,000 elements, so speed in selecting and summing is needed. And while I could do this using `Normal`, `Cases`, and the like, my thought was that the `Query` method would be quicker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
testdb[
    All,
    <|
        "LOCATION" -> "LOCATION",
        "NEWDATA" -> Total @* (Pick[#DATA2, Between[{5,8}] /@ #DATA1]&)
    |>
]
```

[image]

If `#DATA1/#DATA2` are very long, then you might want to use something like:

```
Pick[#DATA2, Unitize @ Clip[#DATA2, {5, 8}, {0, 0}], 1]&
```

instead of

```
Pick[#DATA2, Between[{5,8}] /@ #DATA2]&
```

Comment: Awesome. The second operator function is orders of magnitude faster for my case.