# Clip, Select, FirstPosition not working for extracting values from an association based on a range from another list

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, associations

I have this dataset of associations:

```
data = {<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", 
"X" -> {7.96439, 7.85037, 18.128, 6.57162, 14.596, 8.12374, 18.6779, 19.67001, 21.6372, 22.0001, 1.9807,5.8007},
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}, "A"->.....|> }
```

I would like to select a range of X based on a range in Y and then sum it up. I tried the following from [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/replace-the-values-of-second-position-in-a-list-with-the-values-of-another-list?rq=1) and [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/replace-the-values-of-second-position-in-a-list-with-the-values-of-another-list?rq=1) but I think I'm stuck with syntax format errors as it doesn't seem to work:

```
test = <|"A" -> #["A"], 
"X" -> 
 Total@Select[#["X"], 
   FirstPosition[#["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23] =!= {} &]|> & /@ data


test = <|"A" -> #["A"], 
    "X" -> 
     Total@Pick[#["X"], 
       20 <= #["Y"] <= 23 & /@ #["Y"]]|> & /@ 
  data
```

I tried this as well, I sort of knew it would not work but I was hoping this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152339/query-from-association-of-associations-dataset) could have been helpful:

```
    test = <|"A" -> #["A"], 
     "X" -> 
      Total[Clip[#["X"], {10, 12}, {0, 0}] & /@ 
        Select[data, 
         20 <= #["Y"] <= 23 &]]|> & /@ data;
```

Finally, I tried `Transpose` to select based on values, but I would still want to keep `A` association as I will need to append them later to a list with matching associations

```
  test2 = <|Transpose@{#X, #Y}|> & /@ 
  data
test3 = Total@Select[#[[2]] & /@ #, 20 <= #[[1]] <= 23 &] & /@ test2
```

Ideal outcome would be:

```
result = {<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", X->"40.51438"|>,....}
```

Comment: Maybe `<|data, "X" -> Select[Flatten@data[[All, "X"]], 10 <= # <= 12 &]|>`

Comment: @eldo it does select the specified range from `X`, how do I link it to the corresponding range of `Y`?

Comment: `<|data, "X" -> Select[Flatten@data[[All, "Y"]], 10 <= # <= 12 &]|>`

Comment: @eldo `Y` has varying range I don't know specific values for. I just know that it corresponds to `X` positions.

Comment: @eldo, `<|data, "X" -> Select[Flatten@data[[All, "Y"]], 10 <= # <= 12 &]|>` just replaces values for `X` with `Y`.

Comment: Shouldn't your ideal outcome be `{<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X"->22.1053|>,....}` ?  How are you getting `"X"->11.23`?

Comment: @Edmund that wasn't a true example. I have just put in randomly generated values. But on my real data I don't get the right range of values when I try any of the above.

Comment: What is the expected result for the example association provided?  Should it be zero since none of the Y are between 10 and 12?

Comment: @Edmund I've edited the values accordingly. Expected value should be a summation of the range of `X` based on corresponding range of `Y`. So the values in the question should be 40.51438.

Comment: The lists aren't the same length. What do you want to happen if the positions you select for Y don't exist in X?

Comment: @lericr I apologize for not matching length for the example data, just wanted to improve readability - it's edited now. They all have matching length in `data`, that's why I tried to transpose them as a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should eliminate the curly brackets:

```
dt = <|data|>
```

<|"A" -> "2017011_230833",
"X" -> {7.96439, 7.85037, 18.128, 6.57162, 14.596, 8.12374, 18.6779},
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>

```
<|dt, "X" -> Total @ Extract[dt["X"], Position[dt["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23]]|>
```

<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X" -> 40.5144, "Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>

**Revision 1** (based upon comment)

```
data = {<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X" -> {7.96439, 7.85037, 18.128, 6.57162, 14.596, 8.12374,  18.6779}, "Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>, <|"A" -> "2018011_xxxxxx", "X" -> {17.9, 17.8, 28.128, 16.5, 24.6, 18.1, 18.6}, "Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>};

Query[All, <|#, "X" -> Total @ Extract[#["X"], Position[#["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23]]|> &] @ data
```

{<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X" -> 40.5144,
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>, <|"A" ->
"2018011_xxxxxx", "X" -> 80.328,
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>}

**Or, if you want to omit the indices:**

```
res = 
   Query[All /* KeyTake[{"A", "X"}], <|#, "X" -> Total @
       Extract[#["X"], Position[#["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23]]|> &] @ data
```

{<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X" -> 40.5144|>, <|"A" ->"2018011_xxxxxx", "X" -> 80.328|>}

```
res // Dataset
```

[image]

The correct syntax for disjoint ranges would be:

```
Query[All, <|#, "X" -> Total @ Extract[#["X"], 
   Position[#["Y"], x_ /; (20 <= x <= 23 || 25 <= x <= 26)]]|> &] @ data
```

{<|"A" -> "2017011_230833", "X" -> 67.316,
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>, <|"A" ->
"2018011_xxxxxx", "X" -> 117.028,
"Y" -> {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}|>}

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Having a bit of trouble mapping on all associations - it just duplicates one value. `<| "A" -> #"A",  "X" -> Total@Extract[data["X"],Position[data["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23]]|> & /@ data`

Comment: See last revision

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried this as well `test = 
 Map[<|"A" -> #["A"], "X" ->  Total@Extract[#"X",  Position[#"Y", x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23]]|> &,   data]`. If I wanted to perform multiple summation (`X = Y2-Y1`), is this correct syntax? `test = Map[<|"A" -> #["A"], "X" -> Total @ Extract[#["X"],[Position[#["Y"], x_ /; 20 <= x <= 23], Position[#["Y"], x_ /; 25 <= x <= 29]]]|> &, data]`

Comment: See revision - And yes, your `Map` and my `Query` do the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty jenky, but I think it gives you what you're asking for.

```
Yselector = 20 <= # <= 23 &;
<|"A" -> #["A"], "X" -> Total[Pick[#["X"], Yselector /@ #["Y"]]]|> & /@ data
```

I assume that you intended `data` to have multiple associations instead of just one association that repeats keys.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. What if I want total to be the sum of one range minus the sum of another range? Will this work? `Y1 = 20 <= # <= 23 &; Y2 = 25 <= # <= 30 &;` Giving `<|"A" -> #["A"], "X" -> Total[Pick[#["X"], Y2]] - Total[Pick[#["X"], Y1]]|> & /@ data`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah but I forgot to map over `Y`.  So this work, `<|"A" -> #["A"], "X" -> Total[Pick[#["X"], Y2 /@ #["Y"]]] - Total[Pick[#["X"], Y1 /@ #["Y"]]]|> & /@ data`